# Animate a button to the left and right with 20 pixels

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I want to have my button moved with 20 pixels to the left and I want it after 0.25 second back at the original spot. This is what i got so far:

```
@IBOutlet weak var Like: UIButton!

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
                       animations: {
                        var likeframe = self.Like.frame
                        likeframe.origin.x -= 20
        },
                       completion: { _ in
                        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
                            var likeframe = self.Like.frame
                            likeframe.origin.x += 20

        }
})
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the frame itself

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,animations: {
          self.Like.frame =  self.Like.frame.offsetBy(dx:-20,dy:0)

        }) { _ in

           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25 , animations: {
            self.Like.frame =  self.Like.frame.offsetBy(dx:20,dy:0)

           })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the frame and use the delay function to delay the animation

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25,
               animations: {
                Like.frame.origin.x -= 20

},
               completion: { _ in
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25, delay: 0.25, options: [], animations: {
                    Like.frame.origin.x += 20
                }, completion: nil)
})
```